# How to use generate inside testbench to instantiate different test modules?

Tags: verilog, test-bench

I am trying to run different testing procedures inside my testbench and have run them depending on which generate flag I set. Note, the below code is what I am defining to ModelSim as the top level. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
module testbench
#( parameter FLAG1 = 0, parameter FLAG2 = 1)();
    ... // code here
    generate
        if (FLAG1 == 1)
            Component1(signals);
        else if (FLAG2 == 1)
            Component2(signals);
        else
            // set everything to zero
    endgenerate
endmodule
```

With this, I just want to be able to set the default value of the parameter inside this testbench and run different cases. This compiles fine in ModelSim PE Student Edition 10.4a, but when I go to add the signals from the generated instance name, Modelsim does not recognize that the instance exists?

```
** Error: (vish-4014) No objects found matching 'spi_tb/uut4/*'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It does work, modelsim just names the instance genblk[i]/youInstanceNameHere.

Comment: FYI, you choose the name of the generate block by applying a label (ex: `if (FLAG1 == 1) begin : genFlag1`); otherwise you get the default genblk[i] syntax.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Do you know how to add waves to ModelSim in a .do file with this method? When I try the following, it does not recognize it and complains about the number inside the brackets even though this is how the GUI shows the instance name: `#add wave -group dbnc $top_level/uut1/debouncegen[0]/debounce/*`

Comment: I not sure ModelSim specifically, but I've seen other simulators accept the path with quotes to get around special conditions like escape names. so try `#add wave -group dbnc "$top_level/uut1/debouncegen[0]/debounce/*"`